# how to make an array with several id's to a video tag with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using a custom build html5 video. The video tag has an unique id. Now i want to create several video tags.

This is how it works wit only 1 video:

```
<video id="myVideo1" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350" >
<source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var video = $('#myVideo1);
   // stuff goes her...
```

So: how can i make several video tags with each his own id and trigger with javascript on these id's?

How to handle with several videos, independent from each other like below?

```
 <video id="myVideo1" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350" >
    <source src="test1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>

 <video id="myVideo2" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350" >
    <source src="test2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>

 <video id="myVideo3" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350" >
    <source src="test3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

Code to start the video:

```
//bind video events
    $('.videoContainer')
    .append('<div id="init"></div>')
    .hover(function() {
        $('.control').stop().animate({'bottom':0}, 500);
        $('.caption').stop().animate({'top':0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        if(!volumeDrag && !timeDrag){
            $('.control').stop().animate({'bottom':-45}, 500);
            $('.caption').stop().animate({'top':-45}, 500);
        }
    })
    .on('click', function() {
        $('#init').remove();
        $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
        $(this).unbind('click');
        video[0].play();
    });
    $('#init').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always select the actual element instead of relying on id's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('video').each(function(){
       var video = $(this);

       // Do the rest of the instructions.
   });
});
```

Comment: well, the problem is: the second video also starts playing when start to play the first one...

Comment: @JackMaessen could you post the code you use to start the videos?

Comment: Can you give us the full code? HTML and JS. Some things just don't match in your code.